# Login into Salesforce android application using Trailhead account

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am beginner in salesforce. I am using my Gmail account to login to trailhead account. I want to login to salesforce android mobile app using this account. How can I do that ?

I have tried logging in directly using my Gmail ID and Gmail Password in its android app but it says username and password is not present. Please note that I haven't created any separate account in trailhead. I am just using my Google account to login into trailhead and want to login with the same account in salesforce android mobile app

This may be a general question, but I am new to this hence not sure how to do this. I googled and found many links explaining to login using trailhead account. It mention simply login with your trailhead ID and password. However, I am login using Google account hence I don't have any password. I simply select login using Google and it ask for google password when I am logging in on trailhead

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's trailhead for that ;) https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/trailhead_playground_management

In the browser, once you have launched your trailhead playground org you might see a nice starter app. If it's not there (old org or a standalone Developer Edition that you just linked to Trailhead) you'll have to go to setup -> users, write down your username and click the "reset password" button. You'll then receive link to set new password in your mailbox.